# Restrict access through IP addresses to particular pages of RestService

Tags: c#, rest, iis

I've developed a RestService through C# that gets the petition in this way:

```
{server}/user/{action}
{server}/auth/{action}
```

...

I don't want people to access directly to the webservice, instead it's just the web server who has to access. I have successfully achieved this denying every IP except the webserver, but I realized now that there's a part of the site that should actually have public access.

EDIT: What I've done to deny every petition is the use of the feature "IPv4 Address and Domain Restrictions" from IIS, denying access to unspecified clients in the settings and finally adding just one allow entry to the ip I of the web server

So, what I want is to keep the actual behaviour, except for the case of pages like:

```
{server}/admin/{action}
```

How can I achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: You should probably add how you denied every IP except the web-server. The specific mechanism you used is likely to be important.

Comment: I'm not too sure what you are saying here but it sounds like you have denied public access to every part of the page. You need to have one portion of the page available to the public, is this correct?. Instead of blacklisting all IP's have you considered whitelisting the servers MAC address?

Comment: That's exactly it Chris, I've added this in my question now. I don't see how using the MAC address instead of the IP can help me achieving this...